# Linked List ostream overload weird values

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I'm realitively new to using linked lists. I'm trying to overload the ostream opperator for a doubly linked list with decleration :

```
template <class T> 
class DynamicList;

template <class T>

template <class T> 
class DynamicList 
{ 
private: 

Node<T> *head;

public: 
class Node 
{ 
 public:

    T* value;
    Node<T> *next;
    Node<T> *prev;

    Node(T val)
    {
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
        value = &val;
    }

};
DynamicList();
~DynamicList();


void operator+=(const T);


friend std::ostream & operator<< <>(std::ostream &, const DynamicList<T> &); 
};
```

and function defenition:

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream & out , const DynamicList<T> & rhs)
{
    Node<T>* nodePtr = rhs.head;
    Node<T>* nptr = nodePtr->next;
    while(nodePtr != NULL)
{
    cout<<*(nodePtr->value)<<" ";
    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}
out<<endl;
return out;
}

template <class T>
void DynamicList<T>:: operator +=(const T val)
{
Node<T>* nodePtr = nullptr;
T vall = val;
Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(vall);
if(!head)
{
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    nodePtr = head;
    while((nodePtr->next))
    {
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
    nodePtr->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = nodePtr;
}
```

Every time I'm calling the opperator it gives a weird output for example using:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    list += i;
}
cout<<list;
```

It would give an output like 135727363 135727383 135727383 ,I'd just like to know what I'm doing wrong and possibly how I could solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
T* value;
```

You are storing the address of a value.
The problem is that you are storing the address of a variable that has gone out of scope.

```
T vall = val;
Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(vall);
```

The variable `vall` is local to the function `operator +=` which means after it exists it no longer exists (and can contain anything).

To fix change the node to store the value.

```
class Node 
{ 
 public:

    T        value;    // Notice no star here.
    Node<T> *next; 
    Node<T> *prev;

    Node(T const& val)      // Add `const&` here to avoid a copy.
    {
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
        value = val;        // Notice no and `&` here
    }  

};
```